# How to return data when back to previous activity?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have screen activity with code like this,

```
onTap: () { 
   Navigator.of(context).pop('lorem ipsum');
}
```

so, when I press the button `(onTap)`, the screen will return to the previous activity and display text of "lorem ipsum", how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your 1st Screen use this (when you want to go to Screen2)

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()))
    .then((string) {
      // string here is lorem ipsum
});
```

In your 2nd screen when you go back to 1st, use this

```
Navigator.pop(context, 'lorem ipsum');
```

Comment: where I have to put Navigator.push(.... ? in class _Page1 extends State<Page1> or ?...

Comment: `Navigator.push()` should be used in screen 1 when you go to your screen 2, maybe you are using a button for this. If not, tell me how you are navigating to screen 2?

Comment: I use this, return new GestureDetector( onTap: () async {  Navigator.pop(context, 'lorem ipsum'); }) so, text on previous screen will changed

Comment: No, I asked you how you are going to your second screen where you are using the code you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in flutter, `Activity` term is not used. Everything is a `Widget`.

When you pushed to this screen, you have to push `MaterialRouteWidget` whose parameter should be same as pop's result (in your case - String) like this -

```
new RaisedButton(onPressed: ()async{
  String value = await Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute<String>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new Center(
          child: new GestureDetector(
              child: new Text('OK'),
              onTap: () { Navigator.pop(context, "lorem ipsum"); }
          ),
        );
      }
  )
  );
  print(value);

},
  child: new Text("Return"),)
```

To understand this properly, please go through [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [popAndPushNamed](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html) and add your text as arguments

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/yourRoute', arguments: 'your text' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

**1) in first page (go to second page/activity)**

```
Future _buttonTapped() async {
   Map results =  await Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
   builder: (BuildContext context) {
   return new SelectionPage();
   },
  ));

  if (results != null && results.containsKey('selection')) {
    setState(() {
     _selection = results['selection'];
    });
  }
}
```

**2) in the second page (from where you want to pass value)**

```
onTap: () { 
   String value = "lorem ipsum";
   Navigator.of(context).pop({'selection':value});
}
```

[Here](http://cogitas.net/startactivityforresult-flutter/) is a nice example of how you can pass the value to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

there is an package that you can pass some parameters like url params
https://github.com/theyakka/fluro

router.define("/users/:id", handler: usersHandler);

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you need a result from the page B to A... you need to expect it in page A

For example...

You have a button that goes to the page B, then you need the next code:

```
String informationFromPageB = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => PageB(),
);
```

Then in the page B, just send the parameter

```
Navigator.pop(context, "theInformationHere");
```

You have an example here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Also I did another small example: https://dartpad.dev/f13ca924e567674d872dc45662483941